# Async TPL deadlock with third party lib aka wild goose chase

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

After spending a very frustrating and unproductive day on this, I'm posting here in search of help.

I am using a third-party library that initiates a network connection in an unknown manner (I do know however it's a managed wrapper for an unmanaged lib). It lets you know about the status of the connection by invoking an event `StatusChanged(status)`.

Since obviously invoking the network is costly and I may not need it for my `Service`, I inject an `AsyncLazy<Connection>` which is then invoked if necessary. The Service is accessed by `ParallelForEachAsync` which is an extension I made to process `Tasks` concurrently, based on [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx).

If accessed sequentially, all is well. Any concurrency, even 2 parallel tasks will result in a deadlock 90% of the time. I know it's definitely related to how the third-party lib interacts with my code because a) I am not able to reproduce the effect using the same structure but without invoking it and b) the event `StatusChanged(Connecting)` is received fine, at which point I assume the network operation is started and I never get a callback for `StatusChanged(Connected)`.

Here's a as-faithful-as-possible repro of the code structure which doesn't reproduce the deadlock unfortunately.

Any ideas on how to go about resolving this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AsyncContext.Run(() => MainAsync(args));
    }

    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        var lazy = new AsyncLazy<Connection>(() => ConnectionFactory.Create());
        var service = new Service(lazy);

        await Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
            .ParallelForEachAsync(10, async i =>
            {
                await service.DoWork();
                Console.WriteLine("did some work");
            }, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}

class ConnectionFactory
{
    public static Task<Connection> Create()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Connection>();
        var session = new Session();

        session.Connected += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("connected");
            tcs.SetResult(new Connection());
        };

        session.Connect();

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}

class Connection
{
    public async Task DoSomethinElse()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}

class Session
{
    public event EventHandler Connected;

    public void Connect()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Simulate network operation with unknown scheduling");
        Task.Delay(100).Wait();

        Connected(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

class Service
{
    private static Random r = new Random();
    private readonly AsyncLazy<Connection> lazy;

    public Service(AsyncLazy<Connection> lazy)
    {
        this.lazy = lazy;
    }

    public async Task DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Trying to do some work, will connect");
        await Task.Delay(r.Next(0, 100));
        var connection = await lazy;
        await connection.DoSomethinElse();
    }
}

public static class AsyncExtensions
{
    public static async Task<AsyncParallelLoopResult> ParallelForEachAsync<T>(
            this IEnumerable<T> source,
            int degreeOfParallelism,
            Func<T, Task> body,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var partitions = Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(degreeOfParallelism);

        bool wasBroken = false;
        var tasks =
            from partition in partitions
            select Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                using (partition)
                {
                    while (partition.MoveNext())
                    {
                        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            Volatile.Write(ref wasBroken, true);
                            break;
                        }

                        await body(partition.Current);
                    }
                }
            });

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        return new AsyncParallelLoopResult(Volatile.Read(ref wasBroken));
    }
}

public class AsyncParallelLoopResult
{
    public bool IsCompleted { get; private set; }

    internal AsyncParallelLoopResult(bool isCompleted)
    {
        IsCompleted = isCompleted;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I think I understand why it's happening but not sure how to solve it. While the context is waiting for `DoWork`, `DoWork` is waiting for the lazy connection.

This ugly hack seems to solve it:

```
Connection WaitForConnection()
    {
        connectionLazy.Start();
        var awaiter = connectionLazy.GetAwaiter();
        while (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        return awaiter.GetResult();
    }
```

Any more elegant solutions?

Comment: Why do you include the network status stuff in the parallel for each (presumably it's somewhere in `service.DoWork`? Don't you want to do that only once? Also, are you sure that the library is thread safe?

Comment: Basically `DoWork()` will need data which may or may not be found in a local cache. If it's not found, it fetches it from the network. I think it is thread-safe but seems to be irrelevant since it's only invoked from one thread...

Comment: You do have a `ParallelForEachAsync` which spawns multiple tasks, each calling `service.DoWork` (possibly) in parallel. That does not make it single-threaded.

Comment: Invoking connection methods in parallel works just fine. Connecting doesn't. i.e. if you take out the lazy initialization and just start the connection before the parallel loop, it'll work as expected.

Comment: I visited [the link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx) you mentioned but did not find `ParallelForEachAsync` there.

Comment: Look again, it's at the end of the post.

Comment: It's very difficult to determine what's wrong here, since the 3rd-party lib is a black box and there's no repro. If I had to guess, I would say that it's possible the 3rd-party lib is assuming that the thread that called it is pumping STA messages. The best option is to follow up with the authors of the 3rd-party lib.

Comment: @StephenCleary, thank you for posting. I'll try there too but I don't expect much because as I said it's a managed wrapper for an unmanaged lib and doesn't use many C# features so I doubt they'll know that much. At any rate, if your assumption about STA is correct, is there a remedy?

Comment: @georgiosd: I recommend using full WPF or WinForms thread loops to do STA, but you could also try `AsyncContextThread` from my AsyncEx library and pass `true` to the constructor.

Comment: @StephenCleary, unfortunately this is not a UI application but you Sir, are an async magician. This seems to work: `AsyncContext.Run(async () => { var t = new AsyncContextThread(true); await t.Factory.Run(() => new Program().MainAsync(args)); await t.JoinAsync(); });`. If you'd like to write an answer with it explaining a bit, I'll accept so you can get your well-deserved rep. This may also be the only `AsyncContextThread` sample on the net beyond your unit tests! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the 3rd-party library is requiring some kind of STA pumping. This is fairly common with old-style asynchronous code.

I have a type `AsyncContextThread` that you can try, passing `true` to the constructor to enable manual STA pumping. `AsyncContextThread` is just like `AsyncContext` except it runs the context within a new thread (an STA thread in this case).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (var thread = new AsyncContextThread(true))
  {
    thread.Factory.Run(() => MainAsync(args)).Wait();
  }
}
```

or

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  AsyncContext.Run(() => async
  {
    using (var thread = new AsyncContextThread(true))
    {
      await thread.Factory.Run(() => MainAsync(args));
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `AsyncContextThread` will not work in *all* STA scenarios. I have run into issues when doing (some rather twisted) COM interop that required a true UI thread (WPF or WinForms thread); for some reason the STA pumping wasn't sufficient for those COM objects.

Comment: Let's note that at the time of this writing, the `AsyncContextThread(true)` ctor appears only in the prerelease nuget!

Comment: True. In earlier versions, `AsyncContextThread` would do this thing where it would try to pump STAs automatically if it was on a platform that supported it, but it just never worked very well (especially considering cross-platform code). So in the new version it will be an explicit request.